# Do-while loop in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

So I want to first execute a bunch of code, and *then* ask the user if he wants to do that again. I thought the most convenient way to do this would be a do-while loop like in C++, and since I couldn't seem to find any do-while functions in Clojure, I wrote the following:

```
(defmacro do-while
  "Executes body before testing for truth expression"
  [test & body]
  `(do (do ~@body) (while ~test ~@body)))
```

Would there be a better (as in more idiomatic Clojure-ish) way of writing this macro, or perhaps a better way of doing what I want without going through the do-while route?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a slightly changed version of [Clojure's `while` macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/while), where the test is done after evaluating the body:

```
(defmacro do-while
  [test & body]
  `(loop []
     ~@body
     (when ~test
       (recur))))
```